# Plotting graph an answer to traveling-salesman problem

Tags: python, traveling-salesman

I need to plot the graph of the solution for the TSP. I am using the TSPLIB 95 library and public problem (ch130.tsp).

I have been given the requirements for the assignment to solve the problem in a rudimentary 3 steps.

Step 1. Select randomly starting city and 'move' there.

Step 2. Select closest available (not visited) city to the currently resided one.

Step 3. If there is any available city, then repeat step 2.

I implemented code that gives me a list - path taken as the answer. Now I wish to plot a graph with my answer that will look close to this, but with only my anwser path. But have no idea how. I tried to make a variable
 `G = tsplib95.fields.ToursField(list_of_visited_cities)` but dont know what to do with it next. Can some code wizards help me with it?

Graph was generated from

```
problem = tsplib95.load('ch130.tsp') 
G = problem.get_graph() 
nx.draw_networkx(G) 
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph of the problem]

Comment: Well, how did you generate THIS graph?  It looks like it has every path between all pairs of cities, including to themselves.

Comment: It is every path avalible. I simply generated it to put in the report, and show what I'm thinking of. I dont know how to generate graph of only 1 path and thats why I asked for help.

Comment: I get that.  How did you generate that graph?  Show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `edgelist` argument to `nx.draw_networkx_edges()` to only draw specific edges:

```python
pos = G.nodes(data="coord")
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=list(zip(path, path[1:])))
```